# MySQL | Mostrar columna con la coincidencia LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Qué tal?

Tengo la siguiente duda. Tengo una tabla muy sencilla que contiene 2 columnas.

- Número identificador de la entrada
- Comentario.

El comentario contiene texto y números de teléfono, estoy lanzando una consulta para obtener las entradas que contengan en su comentario un número de teléfono. Mi objetivo es añadir una tercera columna que muestre la coincidencia para saber que número contiene esa entrada.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla 
WHERE comentario LIKE "%999999999%" OR comentario LIKE "%888888888%"
```

Mi objetivo es que, por ejemplo, si una entrada contiene el número 888888888 devuelva como resultado las siguientes columnas:

ID | comentario | Coincidencia

2 | Buenos días, mi numero es el 888888888 y el de mi esposa 222222222 | 888888888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el condicional case para devolver un valor en la columna adicional.

Cuando la columna comentario contiene lo buscado, entonces devuelvo el literal y si no devolvemos null

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN comentario LIKE "%999999999%" THEN "999999999" 
               WHEN comentario LIKE "%888888888%" THEN "888888888" 
               ELSE NULL END AS Coincidencia FROM nombre_tabla 
WHERE comentario LIKE "%999999999%" OR comentario LIKE "%888888888%"
```

[Case when](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!